# Deploy only bot/azure function/tab application from teams toolkit v5

Tags: visual-studio-code, teams-toolkit

I upgraded my project's teams toolkit to v5. The previous version of teams toolkit would allow me to deploy only selected app resources in Azure, for example only tab application or bot instead of the whole project. Is there any way in which I can deploy only one instead of the entire project

I tried to update the lifecycle settings but couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `teamsapp.yml` by remove the part you don't want to deploy.

The original `teamsapp.yml` can be like this:

```yaml
deploy:
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    with:
      args: install
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    env:
      REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID: ${{AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID}}
      REACT_APP_START_LOGIN_PAGE_URL: ${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/auth-start.html
      REACT_APP_FUNC_NAME: getUserProfile
      REACT_APP_FUNC_ENDPOINT: ${{API_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT}}
    with:
      args: run build --if-present
  # Deploy bits to Azure Storage Static Website
  - uses: azureStorage/deploy
    with:
      # Deploy base folder. This folder includes manifest files for AAD app and Teams app that should be ignored using the ignoreFile.
      artifactFolder: build
      # The resource id of the cloud resource to be deployed to
      resourceId: ${{TAB_AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_ID}}
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: install
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: run build --if-present
  # Install development tool(s)
  - uses: devTool/install
    with:
      dotnet: true
    # Write the information of installed development tool(s) into environment
    # file for the specified environment variable(s).
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      dotnetPath: DOTNET_PATH
  - uses: cli/runDotnetCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: build extensions.csproj -o bin --ignore-failed-sources
      execPath: ${{DOTNET_PATH}}
  # Deploy your application to Azure Functions using the zip deploy feature.
  # For additional details, see at https://aka.ms/zip-deploy-to-azure-functions
  - uses: azureFunctions/zipDeploy
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      # deploy base folder
      artifactFolder: .
      # Ignore file location, leave blank will ignore nothing
      ignoreFile: .funcignore
      # the resource id of the cloud resource to be deployed to
      resourceId: ${{API_FUNCTION_RESOURCE_ID}}
```

After remove the deploy process of the tab application, it can be like this:

```yaml
deploy:
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: install
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: run build --if-present
  # Install development tool(s)
  - uses: devTool/install
    with:
      dotnet: true
    # Write the information of installed development tool(s) into environment
    # file for the specified environment variable(s).
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      dotnetPath: DOTNET_PATH
  - uses: cli/runDotnetCommand
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      args: build extensions.csproj -o bin --ignore-failed-sources
      execPath: ${{DOTNET_PATH}}
  # Deploy your application to Azure Functions using the zip deploy feature.
  # For additional details, see at https://aka.ms/zip-deploy-to-azure-functions
  - uses: azureFunctions/zipDeploy
    with:
      workingDirectory: api
      # deploy base folder
      artifactFolder: .
      # Ignore file location, leave blank will ignore nothing
      ignoreFile: .funcignore
      # the resource id of the cloud resource to be deployed to
      resourceId: ${{API_FUNCTION_RESOURCE_ID}}
```